# "fatal error: 'chrono' file not found" when compiling C++ project based on CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Do you know what that error message means and what I should do now?

```
vpn-global-dhcp3-252:build Dolyn$ make

Scanning dependencies of target mdatom 
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mdatom.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/Users/Dolyn/sources/src/main.cpp:124:11: fatal error: 
  'chrono' file not found
#include      <chrono>            
For high resolutio    timings
                    ^
1 error generated.
```

I have no idea about what I have to do now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build error *probably* means that the source file includes a C++11 header (`<chrono>`) but you are compiling without support for C++11.
Given that your compiler supports C++11, you need to activate it using the following line in the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```